# M-Bus (Meter-Bus) Arduino / RPI

Tags: arduino, serial, raspberry-pi

Is there some one that have manage to connect to a M-Bus (Meter-Bus)? With a Arduino or RPI? Maybe a M-Bus to serial is the way to go?

Comment: FYI: This gets down-voted since you showed no attempt to present any useful information you could've come up with by yourself.

Comment: Please read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour then improve your question to meet the site standards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If you want to connect as a master:**
For a quick start: go with the RPI and have a look at the openmuc jMBUS lib:
https://www.openmuc.org/index.php?id=48

I used it in combination with a ready to use (commercial) M-BUS-master-module offering a RS232 interface:
http://www.solvimus.de/en/smart-metering/m-bus-oem-master/
pro: only needs one 24V DC supply, con: expensive (~30 €).

There is a simple MBUS-master circuit shown as part of rscadas libmbus: https://github.com/rscada/libmbus/blob/master/hardware/MBus_USB.pdf

In http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/1944 user Trystan Lea showed how they used the interface successfully. He also referenced a (required) step-up DC/DC converter (XL6009). Sorry - I was not able to get a direct link to the relevant post - look for '29/05/2015 - 15:40'.

**To implement a slave:**
Use the TSS721A (TI - http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tss721a.pdf) mentioned by @Rev1.0 or the NCN5150 (ON Semiconductor - http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCN5150-D.PDF).

Comment: rscadas libmbus is a MBus slave.  MBus master cannot work with optional power supply.

Answer (score 3):

You require some M-Bus transceiver IC like the [TSS721A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tss721a.pdf) from TI. You can interface that transceiver directly with UART.

To be compatible with any common M-Bus master / M-Bus Software, you have to implement the protocol stack according to EN13757.

So yes, in general its totally possible to implement this on a Arduino or RPI. I designed a commercial M-Bus device based on an ATMega644p.